# High memory consumption in hangfire

Tags: hangfire

I notice that once I started my .NET 6 service which has hangfire (version 1.7.31) in it, its memory usage is 26000 MB. And there are no jobs running or scheduled. This memory usage is seen at Azure App Insights > Live Metrics. Other service, their memory usage are only 400-500 MB.

I tried to use both `AddTransient` and `AddSingleton` but the result is the same.

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITelemetryInitializer, MyTelemetryInitializer>();
```

or

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, MyTelemetryInitializer>();
```

I have also set WorkerCount = 1

```
builder.Services.AddHangfireServer(
    options =>
    {
        options.WorkerCount = 1;
        options.SchedulePollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        options.HeartbeatInterval = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        options.ServerCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    }
);
```

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with hangfire as I tried with an empty project and yet the committed memory is high. I think this is probably due to I run from my local development.